# routing error for profile page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and I have at work setting up the user profile and adding fields to it for users to add details to their profile. This information is completely different from the registration options (account settings). The issue I had was the submit button on the profile page is only recogonizing it as the submit button from the registration page. So when users select all their profile options (career, religion, height, etc) and then click submit it redirect them to the registration page and never saved the profile options to the user.

I believe I fixed that problem and I now have a routing error "No route matches [GET] "/profile/4""

Users_controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def profile
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Account updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def destroy
     User.find(params[:id]).destroy
     flash[:success] = "User deleted."
     redirect_to users_url
   end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Account updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the profile.html (renamed from show.html which allowed /users/user-id-here but as noted above I was having issues with it so I changed file name):

```
<h1><%= @user.username %></h1>

<h2>Basics</h2>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :height %><br/>
        <%= f.select :about_me, [['Feet', nil], '4', '5', '6'] %>
        <%= f.select :about_me, [['Inches', nil], '0', '1', '2', '3', '4',                  
                                '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11'] %>
        </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :children %><br/>
        <%= f.select :children, [['Do you have or want kids?', nil], 'Yes, they live with me', 'I want kids now', 'I want one someday', 'Not for me']%>
        </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :religion %><br/>
        <%= f.select :religion, [['What is your faith?', nil], 'Agnostic', 'Atheist', 'Christian', 'Catholic', 'Buddhist', 'Hindu', 'Jewish', 'Muslim', 'Spiritual without affiliation', 'Other', 'None', 'Prefer not to say'  ]%><br/>
        <%= f.select :religion, [['How important is this to you?', nil], 'Very Important', 'Somewhat Important', 'Not Important']%>
        </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :career %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :career %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :education %><br/>
        <%= f.select :education, [['What is your education level?', nil], 'High school', 'Some college', 'Undergraduate', "Bachelor's", "Master's ", 'PhD', 'Business school', 'Law school', 'Medical school' ]%>
        </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :ethnicity %><br/>
        <%= f.select :ethnicity, [['What is your ethnicity?', nil], 'Asian', 'Black', 'Biracial', 'Indian', 'Hispanic/Latin', 'Middle Eastern', 'Native American', 'Pacific Islander', 'White', 'Other' ]%>
        </div>
        <%= f.label :user_drink %><br/>
        <%= f.select :user_drink, [['How much do you drink?', nil], 'Often Drinks', 'Sometimes drinks', 'Never drinks', 'No comment' ]%>
        </div><br/>
        <%= f.label :user_smoke %><br/>
        <%= f.select :user_smoke, [['How often do you smoke?', nil], 'Often smokes', 'Sometimes smokes', 'Never smokes'] %>
        </div>
    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>

    <h3>About Me</h3>

    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :about_me %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :about_me %>
    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here's routes file:

```
Dating::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  get 'edit' => 'users#edit'
  get 'profile' => 'users#profile'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :password_resets

  root to: 'users#new'
```

Comment: can you pinpoint the line that's causing the error?

Comment: I see both the profile and update methods are same. why dont use same method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put in routes.rb

```
match "/profile/:id" => "users#show"
```

Although ,I wouldn't use that approach of changing show.html to profile.html, but this should work in fixing routes :)

Comment: You should not use `match`, you should use the right verb for the request you expect (in this case, `get`).

Comment: In bad situation, there is no good and right alternative. I would not change show, if you ask me :) but ok, thanks for comment. get could be used also.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
get 'profile' => 'users#profile'
```

to

```
get 'profile/:id' => 'users#profile'
```

or a much better solution is to add a member route under users

```
resources :users do
  get :profile, on: :member
end
```

Comment: Yes, that was with updated options as I tried both. Still produce same error unfortunately.

Comment: changing the route as suggested the first way here will work. If it does not, there is something else going on that you haven't shown us, like a full error with logs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly define your path in the form_for as:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => {:action => :profile}) do |f| %>
```